# if quickfixj crash in onmessage, will I lose my current message?

Tags: quickfixj

Need to understand if my initiator received a message but crashed inside onMessage function, will I still restart with reset the sequence number that I was processing while crashing, and receives it again? so I don't lose the message? 
At what point does the seqnum got incremented, when the process goes out of the onMessage function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per code if QuickfixJ, it increments the nextSeqNum to received after processing of onMessage callback. So if there is an exception in onMessage then nextSeqNum to received would not be incremented.
Then while receiving the next message, there would be a gap in sequence number and Quickfixj will automatically send the resend request.

You can go through the code, here: https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj

You can still change the behavior using config: "RejectMessageOnUnhandledException

for documentation please refer: https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/1.6.1/usage/configuration.html

Let me know if you need more guidance.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, the onMessage is a call back function that blocks until it returns to increment the seqnum. Thanks for confirmation. Also, am I the only one feels that the documentation of the quickfix is not very thorough. I still don't quite get it how some of the seqnum or message gap cases are properly handled.

Comment: @baron I do agree that management of sequence number in quickfixj is not properly documented. Although they have documented all the configuration that can be used.